# Snort Performance Monitoring

Tags: monitoring, snort

Using snort version 2.8.6, I am attempting to collect application performance stats such as

- Number of packets *not* processed due to application overload
- Percentage of time in processing layers (preprocessor, reassembly, pattern matching, etc)
- Number of packets processed
- etc

I am currently using perfmonitor preprocessor to dump performance stats, and graphing some
of these values through SNMP calls. The documentation on this preprocessor is fairly limited
and doesn't do a good job of explaining what the fields actually mean, or what time frame the
figures are calculated over.

To get those kinds of performance metrics, what fields *should* I be looking at and how are those
fields measured?

Comment: you might try sticking a bounty on this one to get some attention. I'm not sure how feasible it is to get some of the stats you are looking for, but there must be a way to get at least some of them.

Answer (score 3):

Right now you have performance 'monitoring' enabled, but you want to enable performance and rule 'profiling'. A performance profile will provide stats on what preproc snort spends its time.

Add the following lines to snort:

```
config profile_rules: print 100, sort total_ticks, filename /tmp/rules_out
config profile_preprocs: print 10, sort total_ticks, filename /tmp/preproc_out
```

Let snort run for a while and then when you exit you can see the output files.

For more info please see page 107 of the Snort Manual 
(http://www.snort.org/assets/166/snort_manual.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

[Suricata](http://www.openinfosecfoundation.org/) is an alternative to Snort, and will actually load up the VRF and EmergingThreat rule sets. It's multithreaded and apparently a lot faster then Snort. My colleague says it has much better Debian packages then Snort does.

Here's a link to the engine statistics you can get from Suricata:

https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/Performance_Statistics

> There are 2 basic components to
>   Performance Statistics. First, the
>   module actually counts items, such as
>   a stream module counting new
>   streams/sec. Second, is a module that
>   collects all these stats and makes
>   them available to the admin somehow (a
>   log, snmp msg, etc).